# checkBox is checked ? Looping inside checkbox elements

Tags: java, android, checkbox

```
int count = listView.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View child = list.getChildAt(i);
    //check that child..
}
```

I wanted to use the following code to see if the total number of checkBox(es) were checked or not. Like if I have 3 checkBoxes I would want something equivalent to:

```
if(!list.getChildAt(0) && !list.getChildAt(1) && !list.getChildAt(2)){
       // do something with all unchecked checkbox
}
```

How do I loop through like this, because for one I am not sure about the number of contents in my checkbox.

Comment: you are checking all checkbox are unchecked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the if statement to return the state of the checkbox.

```
int count = listView.getChildCount();
boolean allUnchecked = true;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Object child = (Object) listView.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof CheckBox) {
        CheckBox checkBoxChild = (CheckBox) child;
        if (checkBoxChild.isChecked()) {
            allUnchecked = false;   //one is checked, sufficient to say that not all is unchecked
            break;    //get out the for loop
        }
    }
}
```

`allUnchecked` will be true if all checkBoxes are unchecked, false otherwise

I'm not an Android developer and I can't find the docs for `getChildAt` so I don't know what it returns. If its an Object you can omit the cast.

Its good to check for `null` return of the `getChildAt` too.

Ps: this is not a good code, you can take it like a pseudo-code to know how to implement the logic of how is checked or not, getting the list of the CheckBoxes is your task :)

Comment: please check edited question ... i meant to say if all the checkboxes were unchecked.

Comment: @user2247689 it's that?

Comment: cannot call getChildAt(0) on child.getChildAt(0).isChecked()

Comment: getting the following error: `09-04 07:48:02.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9000): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox`

Comment: Error is clear. It says that you have wrong casting. You are trying to get object as CheckBox which is RelativeLayout.

Comment: @user2247689 added type check

Answer (score 0):

you can use isChecked function to find if the checkbox is checked or not and then build your logic on that.

I would be able to put the logic if you can clarify your question further.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598204/checkbox-on-check-contextual-action-bar-not-working   This is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!list.getChildAt(0) && !list.getChildAt(1) && !list.getChildAt(2)){
       // do something with all unchecked checkbox
}
```

instead of

```
if(!list.getChildAt(0) || !list.getChildAt(1) || !list.getChildAt(2)){
       // do something with all unchecked checkbox
}
```

Comment: Hmmm how do i get the count of checkboxes ?

Comment: You are trying to get the result count

Comment: yes very much ... for one i am unsure of the number of checkboxes that will appear ... and after that i want to make sure that all of the checkboxes are unchecked.

Comment: You can assign false to all the checkboxes

Comment: but without knowing the count of the checkboxes, i wont be as comfortable implementing: if(!list.getChildAt(0)) thing ... because the number of checkBoxes are not fixed ... my question was how do I loop through to implement a logic equivalent to this.

Comment: Then declare a count variable outside for true values and then increment it every time for the true condition occurs while iterating the loop.
After that iteration you will got the checked checkbox count

Comment: refer it as a sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909175/how-to-get-the-count-of-number-of-true-values-in-arraylist-java